# Not able to Build any Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I tried different answers to my question but nothing seems to work.
When ever I try to build any docker file I end up with the same error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package htop
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y htop] returned a >non-zero code: 100
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest
MAINTAINER <my_email>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y htop
RUN apt-get clean
```

The command that I run is:

```
sudo docker build -t demo .
```

I tried different packages also but all have same error.

What I get is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.649 MB 
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM debian:latest
---> 9a61b6b1315e
Step 1 : MAINTAINER anmol1696@gmail.com
---> Using cache
---> 9b4cd05e03fb
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
---> Using cache
---> 7f4979c6993d
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y htop
---> Running in 7a2a26d155f5
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package htop
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y htop] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Please help me.

This is what I get doing `apt-get update` in the docker image of ubuntu:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg     
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

The above `Dockerfile` you gave, worked for me. Try fetching the intermediate layers again with: `docker build --no-cache=true -t <tag> .`

Dockerfile used:

```
FROM debian:latest

MAINTAINER user@email.com

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y htop && \
    apt-get clean
```

Comment: getting error
[FATA[0000] Error: We do not understand this file. Please ensure it is a valid Dockerfile. Parser error at "MAINTAINER"]

Comment: Dude, I am pasting the dockerfile which I used. Also, check for internet as you mentioned err in `apt-get update`.

Comment: Essentially you are not able to update from sources.list Once, that completes successfully you should be able to install the package.

Comment: @user2915097 Sure in that case :)

Comment: stiil not working. i m able to do apt-get install on the host Ubuntu 14.10 just not in a docker image

Comment: I sometimes have weird characters that docker does like when editing a Dockerfile with Sublime Text (blank characters mostly, like space). Try by deleting the whole culprit line et rewriting it without using copy-paste

Comment: @AnmolYadav Check internet or VPN (if you have one).

Comment: I m able to do apt-get update and apt-get install htop on the host machine. Although i m on a university server do i need to use some kind of proxy or something

Comment: on your host, what gives `cat /etc/default/docker`

Comment: # Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, this is due to IPv6 config. See [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5811).

To solve the problem:

1. sudo nano `/etc/default/docker`
2. uncomment line `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"`
3. restart docker engine `service docker restart`

Answer (score 0):

try with this in your Dockerfile

`FROM debian:latest
MAINTAINER xx <xx@yy.com> 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y htop && apt-get clean`

Comment: nope not working
got some thing like this [Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease]
and a whole lot of similar error messages

Comment: try `docker run -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"` and then `docker exec -it $(docker ps -lq) /bin/bash` and then `apt-get update && apt-get install -y htop` Does it work? I wonder if you need to update /etc/apt/sources.list before doing anything...

Comment: this Dockerfile is similar to what I posted and works fine, so ... https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-debian/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: are you connected to Internet? ping yahoo.com or such, does it work?

Comment: did you mean the ping command? than no it did not work. But i am able to connect to the net and i m also able to download the packages on my host with apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer with the help of Pritam Barāl.
The main problem was the dns sever as i was on the university server which did not set a DNS